combine numerous google link into just one
I have about 1,067 pictures in my Google drive. And want to share it to others on whatsapp, but anytime I try to copy the link and decide to share it, i have numerous links, thats every link is connected to a picture. how can i combine all those link into one, so that anyone who gets access to the link would be able to access all the pictures

Add them to an Album in Google Photos, and share the album.

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review to decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.
